# The typed characters not visible when row height in silverlight DataGrid is reduced

Tags: silverlight, datagrid

I have a silverlight datagrid whose row height and font are to be reduced because more number of rows are to be displayed in it without increasing the total height.

I have set its `row height` to `15` and `font size` to `10`. All its content is visible clearly, but when I type in some text in one of its cells, the typed content is not visible as I am typing it. When I am done typing the text and press , I can see it.

This is how it looks when I am typing some text in one of its cells:
[image]

How can I fix this?

Edit: The relevant part from the .xaml:

```
 <sdk:DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="171" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="StockistClaimDetailsGrid" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="756" Margin="0,20,0,0" RowHeight="15">
   <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
     <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="" Width="30" >
       <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
           <CheckBox Height="16" x:Name="CheckBox" Checked="CheckBox_Checked" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}" IsEnabled="{Binding CheckBoxEnabled, Mode=TwoWay}" Tag="{Binding}" />
         </DataTemplate>
       </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
     </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>  

     <sdk:DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Remarks" Binding="{Binding Remarks}" Header="Remarks" IsReadOnly="False" Width="300" FontSize="10" />
   </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
 </sdk:DataGrid>
```

Comment: Can you post your XAML

Comment: @ mridula: Does the problem still exist or was it fixed by changing the `EditingElementStyle`?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. It really felt like your solution would work. But the same happens, when editing the column, the font size of the text is less, but there is this vertical space that appears on top of the text because of which it gets pushed down.

Comment: @ mridula: That top space really seems strange. But maybe we figure out what's causing it. Just guessing: it could well be caused by wrong/negative margins or padding. Try to reset margins and paddig to zero with the `EditingElementStyle` like <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/> and <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>

Comment: @Martin, it worked! only thing is now some part of the bottom is getting cut off now. For characters like `y`, `g` etc. Characters like `h` and `t` are getting displayed whole.

Comment: @ mridula: Well, a `TextBox` usually uses some padding by default (I think it is `4,2,4,2`). Try those values and see if it looks right: `<Setter Property="Padding" Value="4,2,4,2"/>`

Comment: @mridula: Problem solved? If it is solved and my answer regarding the `EditingElementStyle` helped, then please vote it 'helpful' and/or mark as 'accepted'.

Answer (score 0):

The `DataGrid` uses two different `TextBox` instances for just displaying a cell's content and for editing it. So I guess the text style settings got applied to the displaying `TextBox` but not to the editing `TextBox`.

So, how to fix this?
I found the property [EditingElementStyle on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridboundcolumn.editingelementstyle%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). This seems to do the trick.
Just assign the same TextBoxStyle.

```
<Style x:Key="SmallTextBoxStyle" TargetType="TextBox">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="10"/>
</Style>
...
<sdk:DataGridTextColumn EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource SmallTextBoxStyle}" FontSize="10"/>
```

[Edit] I just found out that the `ElementStyle` must be applyable to `TextBlock`. So you cannot reused the Style, but you can duplicate the style and set the TaregtType accordingly. Or just omit the ElementStyle and set the FontSize on the column as seen above.

```
<Style x:Key="SmallTextBlockStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="10"/>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="SmallTextBoxStyle" TargetType="TextBox">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="10"/>
</Style>
...
<sdk:DataGridTextColumn
      ElementStyle="{StaticResource SmallTextBlockStyle}"
      EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource SmallTextBoxStyle}"/>
```